# Query contacts Android

Tags: android

Basically I'm trying to get all the contacts that have a phone number and/or e-mail address. My calendar is only synced with Google, since my phone numbers are in there BUT the problem is I'm getting some e-mail addresses as well and duplicate contacts, for example, I have a phone number and using Whatsapp as well, therefore It's showing me 2 entries of my phone number. Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
    private void queryAllRawContacts() {

            final String[] projection = new String[] {
                    RawContacts.CONTACT_ID,                 // the contact id column
                    RawContacts.DELETED                     // column if this contact is deleted
            };

            final Cursor rawContacts = managedQuery(
                    RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,                // the uri for raw contact provider
                    projection,
                    null,                                   // selection = null, retrieve all entries
                    null,                                   // not required because selection does not contain parameters
                    null);                                  // do not order

            final int contactIdColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);
            final int deletedColumnIndex = rawContacts.getColumnIndex(RawContacts.DELETED);

            spinnerContent.clear();
            if(rawContacts.moveToFirst()) {                 // move the cursor to the first entry
                while(!rawContacts.isAfterLast()) {         // still a valid entry left?
                    final int contactId = rawContacts.getInt(contactIdColumnIndex);
                    final boolean deleted = (rawContacts.getInt(deletedColumnIndex) == 1);
                    if(!deleted) {
                        spinnerContent.add(queryDetailsForContactSpinnerEntry(contactId));
                    }
                    rawContacts.moveToNext();               // move to the next entry
                }
            }

            rawContacts.close();
        }

public void queryAllPhoneNumbersForContact(int contactId, List<ListViewEntry> content) {
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Phone.NUMBER,
                Phone.TYPE,
        };

        final Cursor phone = managedQuery(
                Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
                null);

        if(phone.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactNumberColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);
            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = phone.getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE);

            while(!phone.isAfterLast()) {
                final String number = phone.getString(contactNumberColumnIndex);
                final int type = phone.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                content.add(new ListViewEntry(number, Phone.getTypeLabelResource(type),R.string.type_phone));
                phone.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        phone.close();
    }


    public void queryAllEmailAddressesForContact(int contactId, List<ListViewEntry> content) {
        final String[] projection = new String[] {
                Email.DATA,                         // use Email.ADDRESS for API-Level 11+
                Email.TYPE
        };

        final Cursor email = managedQuery(
                Email.CONTENT_URI,
                projection,
                Data.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)},
                null);

        if(email.moveToFirst()) {
            final int contactEmailColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.DATA);
            final int contactTypeColumnIndex = email.getColumnIndex(Email.TYPE);

            while(!email.isAfterLast()) {
                final String address = email.getString(contactEmailColumnIndex);
                final int type = email.getInt(contactTypeColumnIndex);
                content.add(new ListViewEntry(address, Email.getTypeLabelResource(type),R.string.type_email));
                email.moveToNext();
            }

        }
        email.close();
    }
```